# Does Azerbaijan charge customs on personal perfume collection

Tags: taxes, relocation, customs

I am currently living in Malaysia and will move (long term relocation) to Azerbaijan, but I have a perfume collection of over 60 perfumes and raw materials as I am a collector and I do this as a hobby, all the perfume and raw materials are opened and used, will Azerbaijan customs stop me at the airport and charge me customs?

Comment: Because your stay in Azerbaijan won't be permanent (see your comment in the original question on [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com)), personal property that you have with you when you enter Azerbaijan _and will take with you out of Azerbaijan when you leave_ may be exempt from Azerbaijani Customs Duty. I don't know how this would be arranged or documented or applied for in Azerbaijan...or even if it is available, as it is in many other countries.

Comment: I've [answered](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/174555/37602) this question in Travel SE. I believe the question is generally well relevant to travelling to Azerbaijan.